# Using a for loop to create 20 different objects

Tags: swift, object, for-loop

I've created a class for `Teams` and want to create 20 objects of this class using a for loop.

Ideally the loop should create the teams as a list "Team0","Team1","Team2"... etc.

```
class Team{
    //Alphabetical Order Number
    var num = "0"

    init(){
        print("New team")
    }
}
var Teams = [String]()
for i in 1...5{
    var Team[i] = Team()
    print(i)

}
```

Comment: You set Teams as an array of Strings... It has to be an array of Team, var Teams: [Team] = [Team]()

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no attempt to add your teams to the array and it makes no attempt to set the `num` property of each team.

You need something like this:

```
var teams = [Team]()
for i in 1...20 {
    let team = Team()
    team.num = "\(i)"
    teams.append(team) 
}
```

Note how variables should start with lowercase letters.

Note how your array type was wrong. It needs to be an array of `Team`, not an array of `String`.

Note how your variable declaration `Team[i]` wasn't valid.

You might also want to add an `init` method to your `Team` class that takes a number:

```
init(_ num: Int) {
    self.num = "\(num)"
}
```

Then in your loop you can replace:

```
    let team = Team()
    team.num = "\(i)"
```

with just:

```
    let team = Team(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
class Team{
    let num:Int

    init(num:Int) {
        self.num = num
    }
}
```

you can write

```
let teams = (0..<20).map(Team.init)
```

Result

```
teams[0].num // 0
teams[1].num // 1
teams[2].num // 2
```